# Gradient of a function defined on a torus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have a function given by, $U(\theta_1,\theta_2)=\cos(\theta_1) - \cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)$, where $\theta_1, \theta_2 \in [0,2\pi) $ is it possible to take the gradient in the usual way (like one would in euclidean space?) or do I need to do something funny here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly differentiate the function to get the differential

$$ dU = (\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)-\sin(\theta_1)) d \theta_1 + \sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2) d\theta_2; $$

and for many purposes that one uses the gradient for in multivariable calculus, this is what you want.

To define the gradient vector itself you need to specify a metric on the torus. If you use the flat metric $d\theta_1^2 + d\theta_2^2$ then the gradient is

$$ \nabla U = (\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)-\sin(\theta_1)) \partial_{\theta_1} + \sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2) \partial_{\theta_2}. $$

Depending on your particular situation and application, you may or may not need to get a metric involved, and the flat metric may or may not be the natural metric. I'd have to know more.